# Does a countable fundamental neighborhood system always form a total order set?

Tags: general-topology

A point $x$ in a topology space $X$ has a countable fundamental neighborhood system. Does the countable fundamental neighborhood system necessarily has a total order under inclusion?

Comment: Do you mean, is ***every*** countable fundamental neighborhood system totally ordered under inclusion? Or do you mean, is ***some*** countable fundamental neighborhood system totally ordered under inclusion? No to the first, yes to the second.

Comment: If $\{U_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$ is a nbhd base at $x$, let $V_n=\cap_{j\leq n}U_j$ for each $n\in \Bbb N,$ and let $M=\{1\}\cup \{n\in \Bbb N:1<n \land  V_n\ne V_{n-1})\}.$ Then $B=\{V_n :n\in M\}$ is a nbhd base at $x$ that is linearly ordered by $\supsetneqq.$ In fact $B$ is order-isomorphic to $\Bbb N$ or to a (finite) initial segment of $\Bbb N.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a countable neighborhood base for the point $0$ in the space $\mathbb R$ which is *not* totally ordered by inclusion:

$$\{(-1.5,1.0),(-0.1,1.5),(-0.15,0.1),(-0.01,0.15),(-0.015,0.01),(0.001,0.015),\cdots\}$$

On the other hand, if
$$\{N_1,\ N_2,\ N_3,\ N_4,\ N_5,\cdots$$
is any countable neighborhood base for a point $x$ in a topological space $X,$ then
$$N_1,\ N_1\cap N_2,\ N_1\cap N_2\cap N_3,\ N_1\cap N_2\cap N_3\cap N_4,\ N_1\cap N_2\cap N_3\cap N_4\cap N_5,\dots$$
is a countable neighborhood base for $x$ which *is* totally ordered by inclusion.

Comment: A space where every point has a "nested" (linearly ordered by inclusion) local neighbourhood base, is called an "$l$-nested space". It's not a property all spaces have, but as you showed, first countable ones do.